# Restrict parameter count for optional parameters in php

Tags: php, optional-parameters

From the php documentation i came across the following function:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , 
                       string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' )
```

This function accepts either one, two, or four parameters (**not three**). When passed three arguments, the function generates a warning `Warning: Wrong parameter count for number_format()` on the line of function call.

From what I understand, any optional parameter should be totally optional. Also, php does not support function overloading so that we could have made two different functions to achieve this.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to somehow restrict the number of arguments as above in the function declaration itself (not within the function code)
2. If not, and that the above function uses `trigger_error()` to generate the warning, how does the generated warning refer to the file and line from where this function is being called from. `trigger_error()` function seems to generate a warning / error on the line it is called.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function just adds an additional check of whether you have 3 parameters or not.

If 3 parameters are sent, it generates a warning.

Similar to :

```
if(func_num_args() == 3) {
  trigger_error('Wrong parameter count for number_format()', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

Reference: [func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) , [trigger_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php)

Comment: But will it not generate the warning on a line within the library where this function is defined. In this case, the warning is shown on the line where the function is being called.

Comment: similar logic is defined in PHP parser. that's why PHP parser will raise Warning in function definition level.

Comment: I have updated the question. I want to understand that logic and whether it is possible to implement it in some of our own functions. The trigger_error raises the warning on the file / line  it is used.

Comment: you can control the output buffer & show only the errors on the page , i.e. make use of `ob_*()` functions.